# How to bind event to powershell command output stream?

Tags: c#, powershell

Using PowerShell Object i know how to invoke cmdlets ASYNCHRONOUSLY and bind event that gets fired as and when data arrives as output.

```
PowerShell PowerShellInstance = PowerShell.Create();
//Add necessary commands
PSDataCollection<PSObject> outputCollection = new PSDataCollection<PSObject>();
outputCollection.DataAdded += outputCollection_DataAdded;
IAsyncResult result = PowerShellInstance.BeginInvoke<PSObject, PSObject>(null, outputCollection);

void outputCollection_DataAdded(object sender, DataAddedEventArgs e)
{
    //process output where sender is that outputCollection
}
```

**How to do the same in Synchronous manner. [Note: I should use Runspacepool, which i can specify to PowerShellInstance's Runspacepool property]**

Answer (score 0):

To achieve my objective, i should use variant of Invoke method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh459547%28v=vs.85%29.aspx